# Destiny public events in higher level areas

Tags: destiny

So I started farming public events in Old Russia and wanted to know if farming them on say Mars yields better rewards. I have my route down pretty well on Earth so I'm hoping it doesn't matter/ Has anyone noticed better event rewards from the later zones?

Comment: The only other consideration would be looking at what upgrade materials you need.  I need a lot of Spinmetal, so Earth is a good place for me.  My friend needs a lot of Relic Iron, so it's better for him to do Public Events on Mars and find resources in-between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get Strange Coins, Motes of Light, and Ascendant materials from Earth public events, I don't believe public events ever give gear/weapons.

This indicates that public event rewards are not tied to the area.  You might as well do them on Earth as they are easier due to the generally low-level mobs.

Comment: All of the public events have the same loot drops regardless of location or type. The reward you get in the post office for doing them you can only get once a day *per character* so for maximum farming, make some alts!

Comment: You also have a chance (I'd say 25% or less, based on experience) of getting ascendant materials for getting gold completion on public events beyond the first one a day.

Comment: About 1/4 of the time I've found I end up having to do the events solo. Once you get to Venus (Often 'Vex Sacrifice') or on Mars (Kill the target or Protect the Warsat) this makes it pretty difficult to get Gold unless you're very quick and very powerful. Based on this, I think you get more golds if you jump between the Earth areas, killing the walkers and waves of Fallen with relative ease. It does annoy me though that quite often a random dude shows up 2 seconds from the end and gets Ascendant materials and I dont...

Comment: @SpaceBison Yes pretty much, and that's RNG for you.